# Subspace generated by a closure

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $E$ a vector space, $A\subset E$. Denote $Vect(A)$ the subspace generated by a set $A$ in $E$.

I've proved that $Vect(\bar A)\subset \overline{Vect(A)}$ in an exercise. But what about the other direction? Could someone help me find a contraexample?

Thanks a lot~

Comment: I guess, $E$ is assumed to be a topological vector space.

Comment: Well, we clearly have $\def\V{\rm{Vect}}\V(A)\subseteq \V(\bar A)$, and if we can prove that $\V(\bar A)$ is closed, it implies $\overline{\V(A)}\subseteq\V(\bar A)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reverse direction is not true.

Let $E = \mathscr{l}_2$. Let $A$ be the set of standard basis vectors. Then any two distinct points in $A$ are $\sqrt{2}$ apart. Thus $A$ has no limit points, meaning it contains all of its limit points, and is therefore closed. $(A = \bar{A})$

Now, $Vect(\bar{A}) = Vect(A)$ is the set of finite linear combinations of points in $A$, and this is dense in $\mathscr{l}_2$ essentially by definition. However, you can see that $Vect(A)$ is not equal to $\mathscr{l}_2$, because there are points in $\mathscr{l}_2$ with infinitely many non-zero coordinates, but points in $Vect(A)$ have finitely many non-zero coordinates. Thus there are limit points of $Vect(A)$ outside of $Vect(A)$. This tells you that $Vect(A) \subsetneq \overline{Vect(A)}$.

The final result is:$$Vect(\bar{A}) = Vect(A) \subsetneq \overline{Vect(A)},\ \mathrm{so}\ \overline{Vect(A)} \not\subset Vect(\bar{A})$$